# Implementing basic S3 compatible API with akka-http

Tags: amazon-s3, akka-http

I'm trying to implement the file storage ыукмшсу with basic S3 compatible API using akka-http.
I use s3 java sdk to test my service API and got the problem with the putObject(...) method. I can't  consume file properly on my akka-http backend. I wrote simple route for the test purposes:

```
def putFile(bucket: String, file: String) = put{
      extractRequestEntity{ ent =>
      val finishedWriting = ent.dataBytes.runWith(FileIO.toPath(new File(s"/tmp/${file}").toPath))
      onComplete(finishedWriting) { ioResult =>
        complete("Finished writing data: " + ioResult)
      }
    }
  }
```

It saves file, but file is always corrupted. Looking inside the file I found the lines like these:

`"20000;chunk-signature=73c6b865ab5899b5b7596b8c11113a8df439489da42ddb5b8d0c861a0472f8a1"`.

When I try to PUT file with any other rest client it works as fine as expected.
I know S3 uses "Expect: 100-continue" header and may it he causes problems.
I really can't figure out how to deal with that. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly corrupted.  Your service is not accounting for one of the four¹ ways S3 supports uploads to be sent on the wire, using `Content-Encoding: aws-chunked` and `x-amz-content-sha256: STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD`.

It's a non-standards-based mechanism for streaming an object, and includes chunks that look exactly like this:

```
string(IntHexBase(chunk-size)) + ";chunk-signature=" + signature + \r\n + chunk-data + \r\n
```

...where `IntHexBase()` is pseudocode for a function that formats an integer as a hexadecimal number as a string.

This [chunk-based algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html#sigv4-chunked-body-definition) is similar to, but not compatible with, `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, because it embeds checksums in the stream.

Why did they make up a new HTTP transfer encoding?  It's potentially useful on the client side because it eliminates the need to either ["read your payload twice or buffer [the entire object payload] in memory [concurrently]"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html#sigv4-auth-header-overview) -- one or the other of which is otherwise necessary if you are going to calculate the `x-amz-content-sha256` hash before the upload begins, as you otherwise must, since it's required for integrity checking.

I am not overly familiar with the internals of the Java SDK, but this type of upload *might* be triggered by using [`.withInputStream()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#withInputStream-java.io.InputStream-) or it might be standard behavor for files too, or for files over a certain size.

Your minimum workaround would be to throw an HTTP error if you see `x-amz-content-sha256: STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD` in the request headers since you appear not to have implemented this in your API, but this would most likely only serve to prevent storing objects uploaded by this method.  The fact that this isn't already what happens automatically suggests that you haven't implemented `x-amz-content-sha256` handling at all, so you are not doing the server-side payload integrity checks that you need to be doing.

For full compatibility, you'll need to implement the algorithm supported by S3 and assumed to be available by the SDKs, unless the SDKs specifically support a mechanism for disabling this algorithm -- which seems unlikely, since it serves a useful purpose, particularly (it appears) for streams whose length is known but that aren't seekable.

---

¹ *one of four* -- the other three are a standard `PUT`, a web-based html form `POST`, and the multipart API that is recommended for large files and mandatory for files larger than 5 GB.